# Check if a Set of tuples contains an item with the same elements as a given Set of 2 elements

Tags: scala, set, tuples

Given these two collections :

```
val countries = Set(("Paris","France"),("Berlin","Germany"),("Madrid","Spain"))
val values = Set("Paris","France")
```

How can I check if `countries` contains a tuple with the same elements as `values` ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. `countrys` is a `Set` of `Tuple2[String, String]`, whereas `values` is a `Set[String]`, so `countrys` cannot contain `values`. What exactly is it that you actually want to find out?

Comment: Also, why have you tagged the question with `apache-spark?`

Comment: As a further clarification - is your use of `Set` - i.e. an unordered collection - intentional? In other words, would you want a positive result if `countries` contained ("France", "Paris") rather than ("Paris", "France")?

Comment: @will. Sets have nothing to do with Spark, they're standard Scala. So this question has nothing to with Spark.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
countries.map(c => Set(c._1,c._2)).contains(values)
```

Answer (score -1):

because set are unordered dont use

```
val values = Set("Paris","France")
```

But use instead a tuple

```
val value = ("Paris","France")
```

And then you could do

```
countries.contains(value)
```

Comment: It's not due to Set's lack of order, but the OP's code question won't compile: `scala> countries.contains(values)
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]
 required: (String, String)
       countries.contains(values)
                          ^`